# laravel 5.2 create multi user

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem in  laravel 5.2  when i Register  a new user With A Form All Records Inserted In database in table users But My remember_token Field is always null
If I click logout remember_token will be inserted. but I want to create multiple users from this form
Because I want the administrator alone to have the right to create user accounts
I want when i create the user accounts without  logout for  each time

**Controller**

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{


    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $user =User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
    'droit'=> $data['droit'],
           'idUtilisateur'=> $data['idUtilisateur'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        return $user;
    }


}
```

**View**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="username" class="col-md-4 control-label">Nom d'utilisateur</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('username'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Mot de Passe </label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
...
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i> Ajouter
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

**Model**

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

             $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('droit');
            $table->integer('idUtilisateur');
            $table->integer('EtatCompte');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

thank you

Comment: why do you need the rememberToken ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to allow an administrator to create user accounts, do not use `AuthController@create` method for that.

So, create a form in admin dashboard and just create a user manually without logging in as created user:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    User::create([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
    ]);

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'User was created');
}
```

Comment: Thank  you very much Mr Alexey Mezenin 
Excellent solution
Now I have created another route
Route::post('register1','user1Controller@store');

A small question How can I disable route register by default install when creating  php artisan make:auth
In the route file there are
Route::auth();

Comment: You can try to override it by placing your own `/register` dummy route or you can remove `Route::auth()` and manually recreate only those routes you need (like login and logout ones).